# Is it possible to use "ModuleName-Swift.h" in a pod or static library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa

To access swift files from objective-c, you need to import the `ModuleName-Swift.h` header, as described [here](http://randexdev.com/2014/10/swift-objc/), where "ModuleName" is the Product Module Name (and typically the project name).

Unless I'm missing something, this isn't very good for code reuse. If I make an obj-c class that uses some swift code, my import for the swift class will include the project name. If I want to reuse that class in another project, I'll have to change that import so it includes the project name for the new project.

So if I want to make my class part of a library that can be used by any project, what am I supposed to do?